# Change the default font size in themes in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to change the default value for Font Size in Windows Phone 8. that come from theme

I want to change the `PhoneFontSizeExtraExtraLarge` font size.

I tried

```
(Resources["PhoneFontSizeExtraExtraLarge"]) = 20;
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done directly.

We can create themes or styles that can be assign to buttons and textviews.

Example

```
 <Style x:Key="Regular_24_BlackBrush" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"/>
</Style>
```